# how to create ubuntu installable iso image from files

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, backup, vmware

this might be a quite silly question but I lack linux knowlege so here it is...

I have an ubuntu VPS from which I need to create a development environment under my WMWare. So I wonder if the following is possible (and how should be done): can I download all the files from the VPS using WinSCP to my local windows machine and then create an ISO image to reinstall it on WMWare?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a community called "Ask ubuntu", maybe that's a better place to ask this, some people probably will mark your question as "close" :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly you have a VPS now, in a cloud somewhere, and you have VmWare on your local system, and you want an Ubuntu virtual machine ( guest) running on your VMware that is like your VPS?

If so, figure out what version is in your VPS, and use whatever tools VMWare provides to create an instance of Ubuntu with the same version. Or, I am pretty sure VMWare will provide a free VM already built for Ubuntu. If for some development reason you need specific library versions to match, then use apt-get or aptitude or synaptic on Ubuntu to lock in your packages. Or just update both systems.